# Getting list of activities(Movements) from google fit api

Tags: google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am creating application which can use google fit api.
 I want to get  all the activities(Movements) available in the google fit. Here the list of activities in google fit [Reference](http://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types).

**Edited**

I know the way how to get the activities which performed by user, But i want complete list of activities which available in the google fit API (Not only the activity which performed by user, need whole list of activities) like the list available in the above link.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: I have edited my question please check.

Comment: You want a list of the types of activities that have been uploaded by all fit users combined?  that want be possible.  Just by your authorized user would be a valid request but I don't think it's possible.

Comment: No not recorded activities we need all the list of activity which available in the google fit API.

Comment: You mean this list https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types

Comment: @lfor Yes i need this programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Fit activities are listed in the [FitnessActivities](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities.html) class.

You can programmatically get a list of all these fields using:

```
FitnessActivities.class.getFields()
```

Comment: How can get value of Acitvities from Fields?

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem when started playing with Google Fit API on Android.

There are videos with code samples as well as more detailed API documentation on Google Fit website.

It helped me a lot -- https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-started

Check both videos and later how to save and get data types:

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types

To have some data available install Google Fit app on your android phone. Use it for a while and then you will have some real data in Google Fit database available.

EDIT:

If I get your edited question correctly, then you need something like the following code.
Please note that I use this in my own app that lists activities recorded by Google Fit Andorid app.
I'm not sure if it will list other activities, for example custom data types recorded by other apps.

Request "activites" (like STILL, RUNNING, WALKING) from Google Fit:

```
        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .read(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)
            // maybe you want to limit data to specific time range?
            //.setTimeRange(today.startTime, today.endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();
```

Then parse the response. While parsing there will be activity time available:

```
        Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataReadResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DataReadResult dataReadResult) {
            for (DataSet dataSet : dataReadResult.getDataSets()) {
                for (DataPoint dataPoint : dataSet.getDataPoints()) {
                    DataType dataType = dataPoint.getDataType();
                    if (dataType.equals(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT)) {
                        String activity = FitnessActivities.getValue(dataPoint);

                        /* process as needed */
                        /* the `activitity' string contains values as described here:
                         * https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/FitnessActivities.html
                         */

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Like I said it works for me -- in my own app I list activities (and their type, ie. walking, running, etc) recorded by Google Fit app for Android.

Comment: Not only recorded activities. We need all the activities which provide by google fit api.

Comment: can you give a code example how to recognize which Activity type the results are from, for example RUNNING? How do you parse the results?

Comment: Is it possible to get the "value" beside each activity if exists (e.g. step count for walking, meters swam for swimming, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help others...

```
List<Session> sessions = sessionReadResponse.getSessions();

for (Session session : sessions) {
    dumpSession(session);
    Log.i(TAG, "Activity Name: "+sessions.get(position).getActivity());
    position++;
    List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResponse.getDataSet(session);
    for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
        dumpDataSet(dataSet);
    }
}
```