# get List of all activites listed in google fit

Tags: android, google-fit

I need to get list of all activities listed in google fit just like google fit app .so that user can select a particular activity to insert them into the health kit . Is there any intent builder for achieving this . I read the FitnessActivites class Descripition and Fitness Doc too but did't get the solution .. Can anyone help me out .. i'm stuck here

Answer (score -1):

You can actually get it form AndroidManifest file. Even if its compiled.
Therer is list copied from it (used Notepad++):

```
com.google.android.apps.fitness.FitnessActivity 
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.settings.SettingsActivity
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.DebugSettingsActivity 
com.google.android.apps.fitness.location.MapActivity 
android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY 
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.settings.SettingsEditor 
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.settings.activityeditor.ActivityEdior
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.settings.BleDevicesActivity 
com.google.android.apps.fitness.preferences.settings.BlePairingActivity
```

Comment: I didn't get your your answer sorry . How to use these classes to get list of activities like google fit app .. Can you please post the code you used for it .

Comment: If you need list of activites (like Main Activity, Settigs or whatever else) you can use AndroidManifest.xml file located inside apk file of that app.

The code should look like:

`String s = "com.google.android.apps.fitness.FitnessActivity"; //here you need to load AndtroidManifest.xml from apk of that app
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("com.google.android.apps.fitness.(.*?)Activity")
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // => "Fitness"
}`

Comment: From activity i did't mean .java class i mean activities like tennis, Running Walking , Biking etc .. Which we  insert in fitness app. If you still did't get my point then checkout the google fit app's add activity function

Comment: Then this https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/activity-types or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27163326/getting-list-of-activitiesmovements-from-google-fit-api